# GreenDao query with LIKE clause in related object

Tags: android, mysql, select, greendao

How to use green dao query to query objects, that has LIKE sting in related object?

```
      QueryBuilder qb = mainDao.queryBuilder();
  qb.where(
      mainDao.Properties.Date.between(filter.getFrom().getTime(), filter.getTo().getTime()),
      qb.or(mainDao.Properties.Details.like("%"+ string + "%"),
          infoDao.Properties.Display_name.like("%" + string + "%"),
          infoDao.Properties.Email.like("%" + string + "%"),
          infoDao.Properties.Phone.like("%" + string + "%"),
          infoDao.Properties.Code.like("%" + string + "%")));
```

This kind of query constructed by me will not work? Any suggestions how I could managed a query that checks related field properties for occurrences?

MainDao has foregin key of InfoDao

I think I want to do something like this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Main
    INNER JOIN Info
    ON Main.InfoID=Info.InfoID;
    WHERE Info.SomeField LIKE "%string%"
```

Comment: What query are you trying to do? This query won't work, but I could try to help if you define what do you need.

Comment: I have two tables Main and Info. Main has info object as field. How to construct a query, that checks if Info table row, that is related to Main table, has some string occurrences in its fields.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know if it's the best solution but, since greendao doesn't support JOIN, it could do the trick. Also, you could simply use a SQLite query for this particular case.

Here I'm assuming that you have a relation between Main and Info. If you don't, you could do it with a few more steps.

```
List<Info> infoArray = infoDao.queyBuilder()
    .whereOr(infoDao.Properties.Display_name.like("%" + string + "%"),
        infoDao.Properties.Email.like("%" + string + "%"),
        infoDao.Properties.Phone.like("%" + string + "%"),
        infoDao.Properties.Code.like("%" + string + "%"))
    .list();

List<Main> mainArray = Collections.emptyList();
for (Info info : infoArray) {
    if(!mainArray.contains(info.getMain()) {
        mainArray.add(info.getMain());
    }
}
```

**[UPDATED]**

If you don't have a relation from Info to Main, there's another version:

```
List<Info> infoArray = infoDao.queryBuilder()
    .whereOr(infoDao.Properties.Display_name.like("%" + string + "%"),
        infoDao.Properties.Email.like("%" + string + "%"),
        infoDao.Properties.Phone.like("%" + string + "%"),
        infoDao.Properties.Code.like("%" + string + "%"))
    .list();

List<Long> infoIds= Collections.emptyList();
for (Info info : infoArray) {
    infoIds.add(info.getId());
}

List<Main> mainArray = mainDao.queryBuilder()
    .whereOr(mainDao.Properties.id.in(infoIds),
        mainDao.Properties.Details.like("%"+ string + "%"))
    .list();
```

Comment: It is a little bit opositive .My Main has method getInfo(). And I need to look with "LIKE" attribute in one of the Main properties also

Comment: one remark. You need to  use "`whereOr`" instead of "or" if you want to return "`.list()`" at the end.

Comment: That's true, my bad. Updated again!